# Unable to Login using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I'm using Selenium + Python 2.7 stack.
I want to login to [this](https://www.cancerforums.net/forums/14-Prostate-Cancer-Forum) forum and crawl the post data for academic research purposes. I am using the following code to fill the login form :

```
    username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='navbar_username']")
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("####")
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='navbar_password_hint']")
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("####")
    loginbutton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='loginbutton']")
    loginbutton.click()
```

But I'm not able to login when the crawler runs. It is taking me to the wrong username/password page. I tried to login manually using the same information, and was able to login without any errors. While running the crawler, correct values are filled in the username and password fields. I can't understand what might be causing the problem.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: When faced with this kind of issues, the easiest is to use `Selenium` interactively, and then export the code as Python. When looking at the resulting (working) code, you'd probably discover why your original code failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use wrong element as password field. You should try

```
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='navbar_password']")
```

as this element is `type="password"` while `<input id="navbar_password_hint">` is `type="text"`

As target element is hidden, you can use following to make it visible:

```
browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("navbar_password").style.display="block";')
```

Comment: I tried that too, but since tat field is hidden I couldn't `send_keys()` that field. I checked the form, and on submit it's doing a hash of username and navbar_password field entries. Do you have any idea of how to fill a hidden input text field in python selenium ?

Comment: well, your updated answer script made the field visible and I'm able to send the password value to the corresponding field. But it still gives me error on login, i also tried "form.submit()" style method, but to no success.

Comment: @tortuga: you've selected this as your accepted answer, but your comment makes it sound like this didn't really solve your problem. Do you still have the problem?